# Can I piece together a name for a column that I want to select?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data (called currentdata) formated like this:

```
station   depth     As
   1       -1       0.5
   1        1       0.6
   1        3       0.7
   2       -1       0.1
   2        1       0.4
   2        3       0.2
   3       -1       0.6
   3        1       0.4
   3        3       0.7
```

I'm plotting it using this bit of code:

```
#pick column names from currentdata to extract the metal name
column_names <- colnames(currentdata)
plotting_metal <- column_names[3]

#plot the data
plot <- ggplot(currentdata, aes(x=depth, y=currentdata[[3]])) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  coord_flip()  +
  labs(title = paste(plotting_metal, "standardised sediment concentrations"), x = "depth (cm)",
       y = paste(plotting_metal, "concentration (ug/g)")) +
  facet_wrap(~station)
plot
```

Now, I'd like to add to these graphs some lines that tell me the normal background concentration and a potentially toxic concentration values of these metals. To do this, I made another table, called boundary_values, that has a structure like this:

```
   level      As    Cd    Cr
base_level   0.2   0.4   0.7
high_level   0.6   0.7   1.4
```

Now, I want this code to work so that I don't have to manually enter the name of the metal I need from boundary_values every time I select a new metal to plot. Instead, I want it to take the name from the 3rd column of currentdata and use that to tell it which column to chose from boundary_values.

So far, this is what I have:

```
#pick column names from currentdata to extract the metal name
column_names <- colnames(currentdata)
plotting_metal <- column_names[3]

#get the correct boundary values
metal_values <- boundary_values$parse(text=plotting_metal)

base_value <- 
high_value <- 

#plot the data
plot <- ggplot(currentdata, aes(x=depth, y=currentdata[[3]])) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=base_value, linetype = "background concentration"), colour="green") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=high_value, linetype = "possibly harmful past this"), colour="red") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  coord_flip()  +
  labs(title = paste(plotting_metal, "standardised sediment concentrations"), x = "depth (cm)",
       y = paste(plotting_metal, "concentration (ug/g)")) +
  facet_wrap(~station)
plot
```

You can sort of see the idea of what I'm going for, but it's kinda falling flat in the line where I try to create the variable metal_values. My question is if what I'm attempting to do can even be done in R, and if so, what kind of an approach should I try? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just pass the column name to the [ ] notation.  For example `basevalue <- boundary_values[1, plotting_metal]` works.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 0):

I would do a matching -- try using vector %in% value? e.g.,

```
vector[which(vector %in% c(value)]
```

will return the placement. 
For the data frame. If you do df[row, name] it would return your bound.